# Handling errors with reactjs, react-router, redux

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

For whatever reason, we have an error happening within a component that's the base route. We want to rescue from that to return a NotFound or Error page. Any ideas?

Here is an example of a component

```
function fetchData(getState, dispatch, location, params) {
  dispatch(setTagPage(null));

  if (!isLoaded(getState(), params.regionId)) {
    debug('Component:Region:fetchData', 'Region not loaded');

    return dispatch(loadRegion(params.regionId)).then(() => {
      debug('Component:Region:fetchData', 'Region fetched');
      dispatch(setRegion(params.regionId));
    });
  }

  debug('Component:Region:fetchData', 'Region loaded');
}

function fetchDataDeffered(getState, dispatch, location, params) {
  if (getState().regions.errored) {
    return false;
  }

  // Sometimes when going from TP -> Region, we don't have all the TPs and need to fetch
  const notLoadedIds = isNotLoadedIds(getState(), getState().regions.data[params.regionId].tagPageIds);

  if (notLoadedIds.length) {
    const tagPageIds = notLoadedIds.join(',');

    debug('Component:Region:fetchDataDeffered', 'Loading tagPages');

    return dispatch(loadTagPages(tagPageIds));
  }
}

@connectData(fetchData, fetchDataDeffered)
@connect(
  state => {
    if (state.regions.errored) {
      return {
        errored: true
      };
    }

    const region = state.regions.data[state.router.params.regionId];
    const tagPages = region.tagPageIds.map(tagPageId => state.tagPages.data[tagPageId]).filter(tp => !!tp);
    const regionImages = region.regionImageIds.map(imageId => state.regionImages.data[imageId]);
    const images = state.images.data;
    const activities = state.activities.data;
    const tags = state.tags.data;

    return {
      region,
      regionImages,
      tagPages,
      images,
      activities,
      tags
    };
  },
  null
)
export default class Region extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tagPages: PropTypes.array,
    regionImages: PropTypes.array,
    region: PropTypes.object,
    images: PropTypes.object,
    activities: PropTypes.object,
    tags: PropTypes.object,
    errored: PropTypes.bool
  };

  static contextTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    debug('Component:Region', 'componentWillUnmount');
  }
```

where an error occurs, for example at:

```
const tagPages = region.tagPageIds.map(tagPageId => state.tagPages.data[tagPageId]).filter(tp => !!tp);
```

or in a later part of the component.

Any ideas?